# How to prevent map panning when dragging marker in GMaps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When I drag a marker near the edge of the map, the map pans to let me move the marker beyond the current view. In most cases I would find this a very helpful feature. But it is getting in my way right now.

I tried to to set `gestureHandling: "none"` and that does indeed prevent normal scrolling but the scrolling while dragging is still enabled.

Does anyone know a way to disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the deprecated `draggable` property and set it to false, you prevent the map from panning while you are dragging a marker.

In my case I want the map to be draggable normally so when I start dragging a marker, I set `draggable: false` on the `mousedown` event of `map.data` and `draggable: true` on the `mouseup` event (which along with the `setgeometry` event I use in lieu of the missing `dragstart`, `drag` and `dragend` events.)

I am a bit concerned this might break since `draggable` is deprecated and `gestureHandling` does not seem to fully replace it yet.